# Apptentive cordova plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework, apptentive, ngcordova

Hello i have a need for a Apptentive cordova plugin that supports iOS and Android.
I have found this https://github.com/mcfarljw/cordova-plugin-apptentive plugin but it only supports android.

Does anyone know how can I go about implementing Apptentive support chat for iOS and Android?
Maybe someone can point me to an existing cordova plugin?

My app is written using AngularJS and Ionic.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello softBarbarian, there are other similar products that already have cordova plugins if that interests you. e.g.: Konotor.com supports cordova for iOS and Android (founders will respond and help you through the process once you sign up)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I actually have a specific need for Apptentive product.

Comment: I have contacted Apptentive and they said that they are working on official cordova plugin!!!

Answer (score 1):

we've released a Cordova plugin for Apptentive here:

https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-cordova

Please let us know how the plugin works for you. If you hit any issues, we'd love to hear!

> support@apptentive.com

Thanks for using Apptentive!